# Bash run in background doesn't return to prompt

Tags: linux, bash

Whenever I run a command in bash with "&" at the end it doesn't return to prompt. Instead, it hangs even when the command is finished.

Isn't running a process in the background supposed to return the prompt immediately so you can continue working without hanging till the command finishes.

For example if I run "find" without "&" it executes and returns the prompt. If I run it with same parameters and "&" then it finishes and then hangs without doing anything.

How to run a bash command correctly in the background ?

Comment: It's possible that it *is* returning to the prompt, but output from the program overwrites the prompt text.  Do you see the prompt if you hit Enter again after the command is finished?

Comment: I do, but I also see the entire output of "find" command. Why ? shouldn't running in background supposed to suppress command output ?

Comment: No.  You need to explicitly redirect stdout and stderr to a file (or `/dev/null`) if you don't want to see it in the terminal.

Comment: I think you are looking for `nohup`

Comment: does `find` happen to be an alias? (`type -a find`). It may also be that it doesn't "hang". It just ovewrites the current line and you could just press `Enter` to unhang it ;-)